# C# string.Format with a '+' before object args

Tags: c#

I was looking through some old code and I found that in many places for returning the error message in the output, the developer had coded like so:

```
objResp.ErrMessage = string.Format(INCORRECT_METHOD_EXEC, +apiChannel.ChannelID);
```

And the `INCORRECT_METHOD_EXEC` was a constant string

> "Incorrect Method Execution for the Channel ID: {0}"

I'm wondering if the `'+'` before the object param in `string.Format` was required. If so could someone explain why? And if its not required why is Visual Studio allowing this `"+"` without any complaints?

Comment: Would it be safe to say that `apiChannel.ChannelID` is a numeric value type?

Comment: any examples of `apiChannel.ChannelID` ?

Comment: Is `ChannelID` a number? Then `+` is essentially a no-op

Comment: I'm wondering if the original author had a JavaScript background and was used to having to use that semantic to convert objects to numeric in a loosely typed language.

Comment: My best guess is that this programmer had a background in scripting languages with implicit conversions, and "+" was his way to "force" a "conversion" to a number. In C#, obviously, this is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, its an integer value.

Comment: Then the `+` plays no role. Visual Studio doesn't complain because there's nothing wrong with prefixing a number with a sign. If `ChannelID` was a string,  `+` would be treated as an operator and result in an error

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised that it is allowed at all. I'd have thought that VS would have flagged it. As it hadn't, I thought it was some arcane unary operation.

Comment: Well, it *is* [an arcane unary operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k1a63xkz). Just not a very useful one. It could be employed for readability, if you want to emphasize the number is positive (`new[] { -1, +1, -1, +1 }`).

Comment: @Arunster why shouldn't it be allowed? It's a sign in front of a number, which is indeed a unary operator.

Comment: One possible difference, you can get: when `apiChannel.ChannelID` is `char`, them you will get it code, but not character.

Comment: @PetSerAl: nice find. That should come handy in interview questions: what's the result of `+'a'+"b"` and why? :-)

Comment: Thank you all, you were of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is a numeric value, visual studio won't flag it, it is simply an allowed move.

```
int i=7;

string str= String.Format("blabla {0}", +i);
```

will output :

> blabla 7

And

```
string str= String.Format("blabla {0}", -i); //note that this will output the negative value of i, which may be useful in some cases as well
```

will output:

> blabla -7

however if it was a `string` for example, it would have been considered an ERROR

```
string i = "foo";
string str= String.Format("blabla {0}", +i); // operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
```

Comment: `+i` is not the same as `0+i`. One involves a unary operator, the other a binary operator. These expressions have the same result in this case, of course, but it's more accurate to say that unary `+` just returns the value of its operand. This is more than nitpicking: the result of `0+s`, with `s` a string, is "0" prefixed to that string.

Answer (score 1):

Here `+` is acting a the

> [Unary Plus Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365(v=vs.71).aspx)

which is perfectly valid C#. To quote,

> The predefined unary plus operators are:
>
> ```
> int operator +(int x);
> uint operator +(uint x);
> long operator +(long x);
> ulong operator +(ulong x);
> float operator +(float x);
> double operator +(double x);
> decimal operator +(decimal x);
> ```
>
> For each of these operators, the result is simply the value of the
>   operand.

---

Since `apiChannel.ChannelID` is an `int`, the code in the question is functionally equivalent to the simpler,

```
objResp.ErrMessage = string.Format(INCORRECT_METHOD_EXEC, apiChannel.ChannelID);
```

The `+` in the expression has no other special meaning in the OP's scenario.

Comment: I knew about these, I was just wondering about the scenario that I mentioned. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @Arunster this is exactly the meaning of the `+` in your scenario. The result of the expression `+apiChannel.ChannelID` is being formatted into the string in the normal way. The `+` is not directly effecting the string formatting in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Also note that `+` is an overloadable operator, both the unary and binary one. So you can for example have:

```
class MySillyType
{
  int _value;

  public MySillyType(int value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }

  public static int operator +(MySillyType t)
  {
    return t._value;
  }
}
```

Then `string.Format("{0}", new MySillyType(42))` will give you `MySillyType`, while `string.Format("{0}", +new MySillyType(42))` gives `42`. This could be abused for example when using strongly typed IDs (e.g. using `OrderId` type instead of `int`, for example) - you don't want to have an implicit cast operator (that kind of defies half of the purpose), but doing `(int)orderId` is too specific and `orderId.Value` is too visible and explicit, maybe :D And since  unary `+` does not change the value in most uses, it isn't *that* much of an abuse, arguably.

It looks silly in C#, but "operator abuse" is not even a concept in many functional programming languages - operators are just shorter function names :D

It could be used as part of the transition from legacy code as well, of course. It's easy to apply `+` to any variable etc. and rewrite parts of the code independently - for the `int`, it will do nothing, and for `MySillyId` it will give you `int` back. Eventually, you remove all the plain `int`s and you can also remove the operator overload - job done.

But yeah, do not recommend. It is a bit silly :D